# Point out my Fallacy, in combinatorics problem, please.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

> Five children sitting one behind the other in a five seater merry go round, decide to switch seats so that each child has a new companion in front. In how many ways can this be done?

My tries:

I try using IEP but didn't work, please point out a fallacy.

There are $4!$ without any restriction.

Let $p_1$ be the property such that one of them has the same companion in front, similarly for other properties, $p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5$, as well.

No. of way in which $p_1$ occur,

I used tie method, tie 1st one and the 2nd one, we remain with $3$, which along with tied one can be arranged in $3!$ (circular permutations). Similarly for other properties as well.

No of ways in which $p_1\cup p_2$ occur:

Now tie three consecutive people, so we remain with $2$, which along with tied peoples can be permuted in $2!$, similarly for other as well. Total results in $5\cdot 2!$. (need to tie consecutive from $5$, not any hence factor with $2$ is not ${{5}\choose{2}}$)

No. of ways in which $p_1\cup p_2\cup p_3$ occur:

Now, four consecutive people, we remain with $1$, which along with tied can be permuted in $1!$. Total results in $5\cdot 1!=5$

No. of ways in which $p_1\cup p_2\cup p_3\cup p_4$ occur:

Now we'll tie $5$ consecutive, so one way.

No. of ways in which $p_1\cup p_2\cup p_3\cup p_4\cup p_5$ occur:

will be same as No. of ways in which $p_1\cup_2\cup p_3\cup p_4$ occur $=1$

Exploiting IEP:
$$4!-(5\cdot 3!)+(5\cdot 2!)-(5\cdot 1!)+1-1=-1$$

Where I over substracted !!!

Please Help.

Comment: Please comment if you don't understand what I want to say.

Comment: You start by stating "There are $4!$ without any restriction." How do you get this?

Comment: When two people have the same companion in front, it looks like you are assuming that those two people are consecutive. They don’t have to be, do they?

Comment: Does the child in front have the child in the back as his "companion"?

Comment: @TimThayer concept of circular permutations.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but if you have 5 children with 5 seats, there are $5!$ ways to seat them initially.

Comment: First, I think you want $p_i$ to be the property that the ith child has the same companion in front, not the property that $i$ of the children have the same companion in front, as this is how you calculate each $p_i$. Second,  when calculating the number of ways p_i and p_j both can happen, you only considered the case when j=i+1.  How many ways can $p_1$ and $p_4$ happen simultaneously?

Comment: @TheCount may be no, as "in front" is mentioned. and if "in front" has the same companion then, person exceeding it will have same "backward"

Comment: @TimThayer see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html

Comment: It seems that if you are using the idea of "in front", then you have defined a particular circular direction around the circle. Thus, you need $n!$, not $(n-1)!$.

Comment: If there are $5$ elements, the total number of permutations is $5!$.

Comment: If you have $A\to B\to C$, with arrows defining the order around the circle with $A$ in front, then $A\to C\to B$ has the same circular permutation, but *very* different meaning in relation to "in front". These two cases are distinct in terms of "in front".

Comment: @TimThayer I tie $A,B$ as one entity so then we have $3$, which with $A,B$ can be permuted in (circle) $(3+1-1)=3!$.

Is this wrong?

Comment: In a merry-go-round, you do have fronts and backs, so that $12345$ is different from $54321$, but you do not have a starting point, so that $12345$ is _equivalent_ to $51234$. Therefore you have to take the number of equivalence classes, which is $(5-1)!$

Comment: I assume that $p2$ means that two of them has the same companion in front.Clearly this is not the same as$p1$.So $\sum p_i \neq 5*3!$

Comment: @Dario Please elaborate. How can $12345$ be different from $54321$ in terms of fronts and backs, yet be equivalent?

Comment: @Ayushakj What you oversubtracted is that you do not take into account the case where the topmost free child had the 1st tied child in front in the previous permutation.

Comment: @TimThayer It was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: @navinstudent $p_2$ means 2nd one have companion. For Two of them, I used $p_1\cup p_2$

Comment: I can also see one thing that, no. of ways in which one have same "companion" (i.e. property $\sum p_i$) is exceeding $4!$ (Universal-Set). we applied some restriction on it so it has to less than universal set. What you all say?

Comment: @Ayushakj See my answer.You wrongly choose the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have actually two different problems here. Given $n$ children and $n$ seats, the number of ways the children can be seated is notoriously $n!$, the number of permutations on $n$ objects, or, if you prefer, the order of the symmetric group $S_n$. However, if the seats are on a merry-go-round and are not distinguishable from each other, we can turn the merry-go-round and have, say, child number $1$ at the fixed position we want. For instance, this means that $(34512)$ and $(51234)$ are both equivalent to $(12345)$, and we are only considering the *relative positions* of the children. In this case we speak of *circular permutations* and their number is clearly $(n-1)!$ With a more advanced terminology, we can say that we are not working in the symmetric group $S_n$, but in $S_n/C_n$, its quotient group modulo the cyclic group $C_n$.

It is clear that, if we label the seats and start distinguishing among them, for every circular permutation we have only $n$ different seat choices for the first child, and all others are forced to their respective seats with no other choice. In the following I will talk about circular permutations and indistinguishable seats, but if you want the results for distinguishable seats, it will be enough to multiply my results by $n$ and they will be valid for regular permutations as well.

Let’s define $f_0(n)$ to be the number of circular permutations of $n$ objects:
$$
f_0(n) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } n = 0 \\
  (n-1)! & \mbox{if } n > 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

The degenerate case $f_0(0)$ is needed by the following. It’s the only case where $n!\ne n\cdot f_0(n)$, and its interpretation is analogous to that of $0!$ in the case of permutations: no seats, no children, no fun, only one possible situation.

Then, we define $f_1(n) \mbox{ for } n>1$ to be the number of permutations of $n$ objects not containing the sequence $12$, and, in general, we define $f_k(n) \mbox{ for } n\ge k$ to be the number of circular permutations of $n$ objects not containing any sequence $i(i+1) \mbox{ for } i\le k$. For instance, $f_3(4) = 2$ is the number of elements of the set $\left\{ (1432), (1324) \right\}$, i.e., the set of all circular permutations of $4$ objects containing neither $12$, nor $23$, nor $34$. Note that it still contains one element with the sequence $41$, $(1324) \approx (4132)$, but we don’t care: we’ll discard it when we compute $f_4(4)$.

I hope all is clear up to this point. Our problem is how to compute $f_5(5)$ and we can do it by induction, starting with the definition of $f_0$ above and by observing that

$$\begin{array}{lr}
f_{k+1}(n) = f_k(n) - f_k(n-1) & \forall k \ge 0, n>k
\end{array}
$$

The proof is rather simple. By definition, $f_k(n)$ is the number of circular permutations of $n$ objects not containing sequences $i(i+1)\mbox{ for }i\le k$; to compute $f_{k+1}(n)$ we need to subtract the number of such circular permutations which contain the sequence $(k+1)(k+2)$. In fact, they are $f_k(n-1)$. For each of the permutations of $(n-1)$ objects counted by $f_k(n-1)$, we find where the element $(k+1)$ is, place a new element next to it naming it $(k+2)$, renumber all subsequent elements, and we get one of the circular permutations of $n$ objects that we want to discard. If there is no $(k+1)$, we are in the case $k=n-1$ and it is enough to concatenate $(k+1)$ at the end. For instance, for $k=3, n=4$, from $(132)$ we get $(1324)$. Conversely, if we have a circular  permutation with the sequence $(k+1)(k+2)$, it is enough to delete the element $(k+2)$ and renumber all subsequent elements: we get one of the circular permutations of $n-1$ objects counted by $f_k(n-1)$. Again, if there is no $(k+2)$ because we want to discard the sequence $(k+1)1$, it is enough to delete $(k+1)$. For instance, $(1324)\mapsto(132)$. Q.E.D.

Let me give another example: we have already seen the set $E = \left\{ (1432), (1324) \right\}$. It has $f_3(4)$ elements. From each of its elements we can generate a circular permutation of $5$ objects containing the sequence $45$ but not “smaller” ones: $(1432)\mapsto(14532)\mbox{ and }(1324)\mapsto(13245)$. Conversely, for every circular permutation of $5$ elements containing the sequence $45$ but no “smaller” ones, we can delete the element $5$ and get one of the elements of $E$.

We can now tabulate:

$$
\begin{array}{lrrrrrr}
     & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
f_0: & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 24 \\
f_1: &   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 18 \\
f_2: &   &   & 0 & 1 & 3 & 14 \\
f_3: &   &   &   & 1 & 2 & 11 \\
f_4: &   &   &   &   & 1 &  9 \\
f_5: &   &   &   &   &   &  8 
\end{array}
$$

As expected, we see that the values of $f_n(n)$ in the diagonal of the above table form the sequence [OEIS A000757](http://oeis.org/A000757). This answer is based on the literature cited at that link.

We see that $f_5(5)=8$, as already shown in Coolwater’s answer. Let’s recompute:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
24 & \mbox{# All possible circular permutations of 5 children}\\
-6 & \mbox{# permutations containing }12:(12abc),\,6\mbox{ possible permutations of }abc\\
-4 & \mbox{# }remaining\mbox{ permutations containing }23:(1a23b)\mbox{ or }(1ab23),\mbox{ with }a,b\in\{4,5\}\\
-3 & \mbox{# }remaining\mbox{ permutations containing }34: (13425),(13452),(15342)\\
-2 & \mbox{# }remaining\mbox{ permutations containing }45: (14532),(13245)\\
-1 & \mbox{# }remaining\mbox{ permutation containing }51: (14325)\approx(51432)\\
\hline
=8
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks in tons !!!. I think my fallacy was that I tied two and subtracted, then tied three and subtracted, so there may be that case that occurs in both, and I subtracted it twice. And you did it for $2-2$ peoples. Awesome......

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what you are counting exactly.
However, If $f(n)$ is the number of such rearrangements for $n$ children (counting those that can be transformed into another by rotating the merry go round), then we can find a recursion:

Let $n>3$ and the kids wear t-shirts numbered $1,\ldots,n$. In the original arrangement, the kids sit as $1\to 2\to\ldots\to n\to 1$.
In the $f(n)$ other arrangements, there is no case of $k\to k+1$, nor os there $n\to 1$.

Now suppose $n$ puts a head on his successor and leaves, i.e., we convert $\ldots\to a\to n\to b\to \ldots$ into $\ldots\to a\to \hat b\to \ldots$. If $b\ne a+1$, this is one of $f(n-1)$ valid situations with $n-1$ kids (note that it is not possible to have $a=n-1$ and $b=1$); additionally, some kid that is neither $1$ nor the successor of $n-1$ has a hat.

But if $b=a+1$, $a$ leaves with $n$, takes of his shirt and kids $a+1,\ldots, n-1$ switch shirts so that each decreases by one, and shirt $n-1$ remains unused. In the end, we have $\ldots\to \hat a\to\ldots$ where $n$ and the now shirtless kid left. So this is one of $f(n-2)$ valid arrangements and a kid $\ne 1$ and $\ne n-2$ (note that these two exceptions are different!) has a hat.

Because of the hat, we can undo these steps: If there are $n-1$ kids on the merry go round, $n$ simply inserts himself behind the hat-kid.
And if there are $n-2$ kids, then $n$ inserts behind the hat-kid with the shirtless kids behind him, the kids $\hat a,a+1,\ldots, n-2$ increase theri numbers while shirtless gets the then free $a$.

We conclude that
$$\tag1 f(n) = (n-3)f(n-1)+(n-4)f(n-2)\qquad\text{if }n>3.$$
Clearly, $f(1)=f(2)=0$, $f(3)=1$.
It is easy enough to use $(1)$ to find $f(5)$.

According to http://oeis.org/A000255, we have the surprising formula
$$f(n+3)=\left\lfloor\frac{n!(n+2)}{e}+\frac12 \right\rfloor.$$

Comment: I think a permutation like $(14325)$ is included in your count, while it shouldn't, because in a merry-go-round $5$ would have $1$ in front again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one reordering so that each child has a new companion in front, then there are 4 similar solutions. Theses can be obtained by rotating the childs any number of times by $2\pi/5$ about the center of the merry-go-round. Hence the answer is a multiple of 5.

Now I think it's simplest to just list the solutions. Start by choosing a rotation by assigning child 1 to, say, the 3rd seat. Then put in front of him 3, 4 or 5. Then behind him any but 5, whoever is left.

Put the last two childs however it can validly be done (0, 1 or 2 ways (in fact at least 1))

$\{4,2,1,3,5\}\ ,\ \{5,2,1,4,3\}\ ,\ \{3,2,1,5,4\}$
$\{2,4,1,3,5\}\ ,\ \{5,3,1,4,2\}\ ,\ \{4,3,1,5,2\}$
$\{5,4,1,3,2\}\hspace{31.6mm}\{2,4,1,5,3\}$

There are 8 so the answer is $8\cdot5=40$

Comment: The solution for all `n` is here http://oeis.org/A167760

Comment: We have to agree about what we want. I would say that $8$ is the correct solution. Each of those $8$ cases corresponds to $5$ _equivalent_ positions of the merry-go-round, hence your $40$.

Comment: So, in my opinion, the correct answer is [OEIS A000757](http://oeis.org/A000757), _indistinguishable carousel horses_. I upvoted your answer _(distinguishable carousel horses)_ because OP’s requirements aren’t clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main fallacy in your argument is that you wrongly choose the properties

Let us take $p_1$ be the property that exactly one person has the same companion.
Number of ways in which this can be done is $\binom51*\binom21*3!$ Here there are $\binom21$ to choose companion(because in a round table each person has two companions and there are two ways to choose a companion who remains intact with the person.

Let us take $p_2$ be the property that exactly two person has the same companion.

It can be divided into cases

i)When the two persons are at adjacent places.Number of ways to choose the persons=5(if the round table goes as $A->B->C->D->E->A$ Then it can be clearly seen that two adjacent persons can be choosen in 5 ways.)

hence number of ways=$5*2!$(we have only one option for choosing companion in this case)

2)When the two persons are one place next to each other

Number of ways to choose the persons=$5$(Similar to argument in first case)

hence number of ways=$5*\binom32*2!$ Here there are $\binom32$ ways to choose companion(For example if round table is $A->B->C->D->E->A$ Then if $A$ and $C$ are choosen then possible choice of companions are $B,D,E$ of which any two is to be choosen.)One more thing here should be taken into consideration.When the two persons has same companion.It can be done in $5*2!$

3)Last case when the two persons are diagonally opposite to each other

**CAUTION** It is already counted in the second case.

Similarly when three persons has same companion=$2$(two rotations - clockwise or anticlockwise are possible)

Now apply IEP(which has none of the above properties) as $$4!-(\binom51*\binom21*3!)+(5*2!+5*\binom32*2!+5*2!)-2$$

Comment: In the third case, we picked diagonally so we have picked $4$ person (no companion overlapping), why that $2!$, it shouldn't be just $1!$?

Comment: And why 3 persons can have just one way? like $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow D$  , $B\rightarrow C\rightarrow D \rightarrow  E$,  $C\rightarrow D \rightarrow  E\rightarrow A$.

Comment: @Ayushakj please check the edit.I hope it is clear now.

Comment: See this: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1388517_circular_permutation_with_inclusion_exclusion

Comment: @Ayushakj Why you provided that link.There is no answer there as of now. Meanwhile it is of no use asking this question here.You can perhaps delete it from here.

Comment: @Ayushakj If you read the notes at [OEIS A167760](http://oeis.org/A167760) and [OEIS A000757](http://oeis.org/A000757) carefully, you’ll see that the correct answer is $8$ if the seats are undistinguishable or $40$ if they are numbered, and you’ll see the general formula(s) and links to literature proving them. I don’t post an answer because I’d have (i) to at least sketch a proof and (ii) explain your overcounting clearly and I don’t have time right now. However, there are enough comments here to give you an idea.

Comment: @Dario No problem, please write what you know, no proof needed, no need to explain my fallacy, just give your time writing here. I'm waiting.

Comment: @mnulb I have been able to post an answer only now. I hope you are stll interested and that it clarifies the whole matter.